# How do I disable 3d buildings with Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I recently started using the Maps Android Api (V2) and am integrating with a custom tile overlay.  I am successfully able to add overlay images, however they look goofy when super-imposed over a 3d building.  I would like to be able to turn off 3d buildings globally or for specific buildings so that my tile images do not interfere with the 3d images.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google corrected the problem.  3d buildings no longer show up when I draw an overlay on top of them.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2016 v3 SDK for either iOS or Android.

Answer (score 12):

It seems they changed their behaviour again to disable showing 3D Buildings:

```
GoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
```

[GoogleMap Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setBuildingsEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: Note that the above line will remove ALL buildings from the map, not just the 3D renders

Comment: Unfortunately, this disables building from showing completely, not only their 3d. It would be super-cool, if there would be an option just for flattening them.